# How to set up vulkan?

Tags: graphics, gpu-driver, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro, vulkan

Problem: VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

I have ubuntu 18.04, and I've downloaded and compiled [example program](https://gist.github.com/Overv/7ac07356037592a121225172d7d78f2d), that draws triangle. It does not work, because cannot initialize vulkan context.

For install I've used `apt install build-essential libglfw3-dev libvulkan-dev vulkan-utils`

`vulkaninfo` is writing same thing.

Someone said, that I need to `blacklist radeon` and install `amdgpu`. It ruined the OS in a mindblowing way:

- I've downloaded, installed `./amdgpu-pro-install -pro -no-32`,
- After reboot I got console only. I dont want to use console mode OS for debugging graphics APP! So
- Did rollback: `amdgpu-pro-uninstall` and reboot again
- After reboot fullscreen refreshes now taking like 5 seconds, I virtually see scanline, and mouse is jerky. OS is still usable, but very unpleasant, unresponsive feeling!

I did that on windows. It involves 4 pretty standart stps, thay you can do in a single, pretty standart way:

- Install win
- Install amd driver (only one driver, from official site, latest version)
- Install vulkan sdk and glfw
- Install free visual studio community, create project, add downloaded source code, press RUN

In result - You WILL SEE TRIANGLE, running at MAX FPS, that your GPU can afford. It is very simple, and with low entry level. Portable across any gpu, that claims to support vulkan. You focus on coding, but not on tweaking poorly designed OS graphics stack!

Now I need to do same in Ubuntu. What steps should I take?

Answer (score 1):

After a day of shamanism with a tambourine, I've finally figured out: default driver is old `radeon` driver, instead of actual `amdgpu` (probably just because *"it would show picture everywhere"*). So basically you have to take following steps:

- `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
- Add the following line: `blacklist radeon`
- `sudo update-initramfs -u`
- `sudo nano /etc/grub/default`
- Add options, based on your graphics card. (for my 390 i have to enable CIK)
- `sudo update-grub`
- `sudo reboot`

After it you should be using `amdgpu`. To check currently selected driver, use:

```
$ lspci -v | grep -i VGA -A 12

Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

To get vulkan SDK on Ubuntu (you would require at least `glslc`), no need to bother with `tar` - [just check out premade packages](https://packages.lunarg.com/). Bionic 18.04 packages are confirmed to work well on my fresh lubuntu 20.04

PS. [image]

Comment: Really not obvious steps, when you come to this first time. Installing amdgpu from amd site could easily mess up your UI or lead to freezes/flickering, in circumstances when mesa is installed and it screws up some config (you dont even know which and where) so better to use amdgpu, shipped with ubuntu installation, unless you want to do like headless compute without xorg, with Pro series of hardware